# Html helper extension works if I do <%= .. %> but not if I do <% Html.MyExt(); %>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Why does my html helper extension work if I do:

```
<%= Html.MyExt() %>
```

all mvc helpers work like:

```
<% Html.TextBox(""); %>
```

My extension builds a StringBuilder, then returns a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This helper must return [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) (ASP.NET MVC 1.0) or [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx) (ASP.NET MVC 2.0) which is written to the response stream (using `Response.Write`):

```
<%= Html.MyExt() %>
```

This helper returns nothing (void) it simply executes the extension method:

```
<% Html.TextBox(""); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%= command %>` runs the command and prints the returned string. The command must return a string.

`<% command; %>` just runs the command. Anything returned by the command will be ignored.

Most HTML helpers I've seen use the first format.